# How to search for an address without omnibox interfering?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

In Chrome, google search, I'm trying to search for www.outbox.net (not to go to that site). However omnibox tries to take me to that address. What do I do (besides using other browsers and engines)?
gil_mo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type it after a question mark:

```
?www.outbox.net
```

The question mark tells Chrome to stop being to smart and just pass it to default search engine. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to quickly jump to omnibar with `?` already in it, ready to type your search query.

Comment: Nice, where can I read about this option and others?

Comment: I don't think there are more such options, I stumbled upon this one by pressing Ctrl+K which I was used to after moving from Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the omnibox
`site:www.outbox.net`

Comment: No results with your suggestion.

Comment: The site operator site:www.outbox.net or site:outbox.net is useful when you wish to search for a keyword within just the site outbox.net. Specify the keyword as well with the site operator - site:outbox.net keyword_to_search_within_site

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the site name within quotes and search from omnibox, like this - "www.outbox.net"